# Windows 10/11: Why does the API GetMonitorInfo returns wrong work area coordinates?

Tags: windows, coordinates, desktop

Im using the API GetMonitorInfo to determine the working area coordinates but the result does not match with the available coordinates on the desktop:

My desktop size is 1280x960 (WxH). The API GetMonitorInfo returns the work area coordinates 0-1280 for the width and 0-920 for the height.

Now i move my app with the mouse to the edge of the left side of the desktop. After i determined the left position of my app using the API GetWindowPlacement and i get the value "-7" but the left side of my app is still complete visible at the desktop area!

When i test this with Windows 7/8 i get the correct value of "0" for the left window position of my app and this is matching with the work area coordinates from the API GetMonitorInfo.

Can anyone explain me why the most left position on the desktop is -7 and not 0 and why does the API GetMonitorInfo return wrong values when using Win10/11?

Info: the app is not DPI aware and the desktop is set to 100% (no DPI scaling)

Comment: Are you DPI aware?

Comment: The border of your window is transparent on Win10/11.  Makes it hard to see that the window is in fact moved beyond the monitor edge.

Comment: @Anders no, the app is not dpi aware and the desktop is set to 100% (no dpi scaling)

Comment: @Hans Passant Do you know how to determine the width of this transparent border to calculate the correct coordinates to place the window of my app to the edge of the screen? I want to dock my app window to the left edge of the desktop but with LEFT=0 i still have a 7 pixel gap between the desktop edge and the window...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem: with the API GetSystemMetrics and SM_CXFRAME / SM_CYFRAME i can determine the size of the transparent border on win10/11. This enables me to calculate the correct value for the LEFT property to dock the window at the left edge of the desktop!